# Get first and last occurrence of duplicate value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` like this

```
index    col1     col2    col3    col4
  0      11/20    11/26   abc     35
  1      11/21    11/24   xxx     30
  2      11/22    11/27   abc     20
```

Here `col3` has a same value (duplicated based on value).
I `sum()` `col4` from rows based on the `col3` value.

So in this case I do

```
df = df.groupby(['col3'])[['col4']].sum()
```

But with this approach I get

```
index    col3    col4
  0      abc     55
  1      xxx     30
```

I would like to be able to preserve first occurrence of duplicated value's `col1`(11/20) and last occurrence of `col2`(11/27), so the final product would looks like

```
index    col1     col2    col3    col4
  0      11/20    11/27   abc     55
  1      11/21    11/24   xxx     30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby.agg`:

```
new_df = df.groupby("col3", as_index=False).agg({"col1": "first",
                                                 "col2": "last",
                                                 "col4": "sum"})
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
  col3   col1   col2  col4
0  abc  11/20  11/27    55
1  xxx  11/21  11/24    30
```

Comment: Converting col1/col2 to datetime and using min/max might be more robust if we always want to "first" (earliest) date and the "last" (latest) date. (Again this depends on use-case)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas provides [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) aggregations.